# Looking for PC upgade

Tags: graphics-cards, desktop, processor

**Hello community,**

Back in 2013 and build my own PC finaly. But nowdays i think its kind old for stuff i am doing at PCs.

**What I do on my pc now?**

**I like playing games** . Recently i discover That CS: GO consume 80% of my CPU (am playing FullHD) That a lot i think.
I was trying Ghost Recon: wildlands open beta, we frame rate about 20-36 FPS and low settings in fullHD. Other games I play are sometime strategy but also want to play games modern.
With friend we play games and sometimes am a host.

**I am also YouTuber / Streamer**
So i make few videos Ghost Recon form, but also record it with nvidia share (with GPU Takes the hard part). For recording using OBS am with nvidia nvec, and same setting for streaming in 720p30 in some games in 60 FPS.
Currently we streams are ok, but sometimes get laggy Because the CPU and GPU.

**Photoshop, video editing, rendering**
For pictures and graphic am using photoshop Currently Seems like i have enough power.
For editng video rendering and i think its not. Take a long time to make a 20 min video like 40-50 min to render in fullHD.
Just for fun i am rendering Also fractals, but its not import.

Sat Those are the most stuff i am doing on my PC. Sometimes am and hosting games and streaming and so on.

**My curret build**
CPU: Intel Core i5-3550p 
GPU: Nvidia GTX 660Ti 
RAM: 16 gigabytes 1600MHz (two slots)
MB: Asrock Z77 pro3 
Drive: 1 TB Western Digital
PSU: Corsair 600 Watts

**My budget**
I save 400 dolars for upgare.

My opinion
In my opinion i need to buy new motherboard and CPU. I am not a guy looking for graphics.
I was Considering Intel Core i5-7600 or i7-7700 
and motherborad

But i am not sure if it buy new CPU or GPU to boost performence for gameing and recording.
And the same time there is a Ryzens with AMD, onestly i am not a fan of AMD i have a bad experince with Them in a trap.

I want to buy new HW for next **4-5 years**. 
Also i not sure if i need **CPU with K**, beacuse i never do it

**Future GPU**
In near future i would like to buy Nvidia GTX 1060 (6GB). What's to think? ITS good option for me? or should i take Radeon or 1050Ti?

**Anyway thanks for any reply and have a nice day**

Comment: Considering your budget of $400 (USD?), as well as your use-case, my suggestion is leaning more towards a Ryzen 5 CPU rather than an Intel i5 or i7. However, I would like to know if AMD is an absolute no-go or if you would be willing to go with one of AMD's Ryzen CPUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you I would upgrade the cpu and the motherboard. I think your cpu is the cause of your low fps. I myself have a i7-6700k and GTX 660 ti and I can play games like GTA V (120 fps) and CSGO (400 fps) with good full hd graphics. Also video rendering and blender etc.. aren't lagging or crashing.

i5-7600 is good for your use. For gaming alone it's not worth it but for your use it should be good. If you think that there is any chance that you someday want to overclock it I would take the K version. Price is almost the same on K as it is in non-K version. Motherboard does not really matter but take that one of the popular once.

You also need new RAM if you are going to upgrade from 1155 to 1151. If your budget is not enough take only 8GB for now. But don't take too slow RAM. You might regret that later as it makes a difference on video editing and because combining different RAMs might cause problems.

You did not say if you had a ssd but if you don't I really recommend getting one. I like video editing myself and gaming myself and with ssd I can really see the difference. Cheap ssd does not take much away from your budget if you buy your parts from good places.

For future gpu don't take the 1050Ti. That is hardly better than 660 ti. 1060 is a good choice but if it too expensive Radeon should be also good for your use.